# JMeter 4 - can't execute jmeter-server in windows 7

Tags: jmeter, keystore, master-slave, jmeter-4.0, distributed-testing

I download latest JMeter 4,

As part of [Remote Testing](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/jmeter/tags/v2_4/docs/usermanual/remote-test.html)

> To run JMeter in remote node, start the JMeter server component on all machines you wish to run on by running the JMETER_HOME/bin/jmeter-server (unix) or JMETER_HOME/bin/jmeter-server.bat (windows) script.

I try to execute jmeter-server.bat in windows 7
and got the following error:

```
Server failed to start: java.rmi.server.ExportException: Listen failed on port:
0; nested exception is:
        java.io.FileNotFoundException: rmi_keystore.jks (The system cannot find
the file specified)
An error occurred: Listen failed on port: 0; nested exception is:
        java.io.FileNotFoundException: rmi_keystore.jks (The system cannot find
the file specified)
errorlevel=1
```

It seems that a file rmi_keystore.jks is missing. (I can't find it in JMeter folders)

In JMeter 3.3 jmeter-server.bat is working.

**EDIT 1**

after I execute `create-rmi-keystore.bat` it created rmi_keystore.jks, but I get other error:

```
Server failed to start: java.rmi.server.ExportException: Listen failed on port:
0; nested exception is:
        java.io.IOException: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Cannot rec
over key
An error occurred: Listen failed on port: 0; nested exception is:
        java.io.IOException: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Cannot rec
over key
errorlevel=1
```

error from log:

```
2018-02-11 12:09:13,916 ERROR o.a.j.e.DistributedRunner: Failed to create engine at 127.0.0.1
java.rmi.ConnectIOException: Exception creating connection to: 127.0.0.1; nested exception is: 
    java.io.IOException: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Cannot recover key
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.ClientJMeterEngine.getEngine(ClientJMeterEngine.java:70) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.ClientJMeterEngine.<init>(ClientJMeterEngine.java:83) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.DistributedRunner.createEngine(DistributedRunner.java:237) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.DistributedRunner.getClientEngine(DistributedRunner.java:213) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.DistributedRunner.init(DistributedRunner.java:93) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.RemoteStart.doAction(RemoteStart.java:80) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.performAction(ActionRouter.java:88) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.lambda$actionPerformed$0(ActionRouter.java:70) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter$$Lambda$63/2068100669.run(Unknown Source) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Cannot recover key
    at org.apache.jmeter.rmi.SSLRMIClientSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLRMIClientSocketFactory.java:110) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Cannot recover key
    at sun.security.provider.KeyProtector.recover(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineGetKey(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineGetKey(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.security.KeyStore.getKey(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at sun.security.ssl.SunX509KeyManagerImpl.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at sun.security.ssl.KeyManagerFactoryImpl$SunX509.engineInit(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory.init(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at org.apache.jmeter.rmi.SSLRMIClientSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLRMIClientSocketFactory.java:103) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    ... 28 more
2018-02-11 12:09:24,368 INFO o.a.j.e.DistributedRunner: Failed to configure 127.0.0.1
2018-02-11 12:09:24,369 INFO o.a.j.e.DistributedRunner: Stopping remote engines
2018-02-11 12:09:24,370 INFO o.a.j.e.DistributedRunner: Remote engines have been stopped
2018-02-11 12:09:24,370 ERROR o.a.j.g.a.ActionRouter: Error processing org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.RemoteStart@3249a1ce
java.lang.RuntimeException: Following remote engines could not be configured:[127.0.0.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.DistributedRunner.init(DistributedRunner.java:112) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.RemoteStart.doAction(RemoteStart.java:80) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.performAction(ActionRouter.java:88) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.lambda$actionPerformed$0(ActionRouter.java:70) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter$$Lambda$63/2068100669.run(Unknown Source) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
```

**EDIT 2**

I tried to change `server.rmi.ssl.keystore.password` to password I wrote but got a different error

```
Server failed to start: java.rmi.server.ExportException: Listen failed on port:
0; nested exception is:
        java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorre
ct
An error occurred: Listen failed on port: 0; nested exception is:
        java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorre
ct
```

**EDIT 3**

I tried to set the server port manually `SET SERVER_PORT=1099` according to [reference](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#remote) but still trying to listen through port 0

> On Windows this can be done by:
>   SET SERVER_PORT=

Comment: In case you dont want to use SSL for RMI, you can disable the same by updating the "server.rmi.ssl.disable" key under jmeter.properties.

Comment: Disabling SSL for RMI should only be considered as an option when you work in a dedicated/secure enviroment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To solve issue, you need to follow:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html#setup_ssl

The problem was the answer to first question when executing `create-rmi-keystore`

> What is your first and last name?

I should have answered `rmi` as it the default value in JMeter's property `server.rmi.ssl.keystore.alias`

Also (difference from JMeter 3.3) I needed to change JMeter's property `remote_hosts` so that it uses my host name (change from 127.0.0.1)

This is related to :

- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62039

Comment: I am also setting master-slave config for jmeter. Facing the same issue. I had followed http://www.testingdiaries.com/jmeter-on-aws/ for setting up jmeter on remote machine. Please let me know the meaning of "my host name" in context of aws server and client?

Comment: @Ajay when jmeter server is running it print your host name : `SSLRMIServerSocketFactory(host=<This is your host name>/x.x.x.x`

Answer (score 9):

Had the same problem.

To solve it you have several options:

1. Set rmi-keystore password to `changeit`, as described in `jmeter.properties`:

   Password of Trust store
   server.rmi.ssl.truststore.password=changeit
2. If using custom password - add it to `user.properties` on jmeter-server machine
3. Disable SSL by passing `-Jserver.rmi.ssl.disable=true`

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me (with JMeter 5.0) was an dedicated `jmeter-server.properties` file with this configurations:

```
# Type of keystore : JKS
server.rmi.ssl.keystore.type=JKS
#
# Keystore file that contains private key
server.rmi.ssl.keystore.file=rmi_keystore.jks
#
# Password of Keystore
server.rmi.ssl.keystore.password=changeit
#
# Key alias
server.rmi.ssl.keystore.alias=rmi
#
# Type of truststore : JKS
server.rmi.ssl.truststore.type=JKS
#
# Keystore file that contains certificate
server.rmi.ssl.truststore.file=rmi_keystore.jks
#
# Password of Trust store
server.rmi.ssl.truststore.password=changeit
```

I created a `rmi_keystore.jks` file with the `create-rmi-keystore` command in the JMeter bin folder. Then I started my server with `jmeter-server -Gjmeter-server.properties`. Also check then the log from the server to get the endpoint to connect your client with the server as [user7294900](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7294900/user7294900) suggested.

```
Created remote object: UnicastServerRef2 [liveRef: [endpoint:[<this is your server>
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced all the above problems, until i found the solution to it, which is this:

- The error `java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Cannot recover key` occurs when the `keystore` and `keyEntry` **passwords are different.**
- To resolve this issue, you must remove all traces of the past certificate and request file.
- You must generate a new `keystore, keyEntry` and `CSR` and specify the same password for the keystore and the keyEntry.

Answer (score 0):

There are two batch files in your bin folder. Run the "create-rmi-keystore" file first and then "jmeter"

Comment: What do you want to ask? Please be specific